# Is there a way to create a VSTS (TFS) checkin policy to prevent a checkin that has no associated build definition?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Using Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) within a micro service architecture and currently sitting at around 50 CI build definitions. Is there a way to prevent a checkin unless the solution file under a folder has an associated build definition that is triggered on the same folder path?

This way we can be certain that all services have CI builds on first checkin and we do not have to manually (or otherwise) check we have them covered.

Even an API to query build definition trigger path against source path solution files would be enough to generate a build definition coverage report to quickly find any gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can custom check-in policy to check each build’s trigger path. Simple steps:

1. Custom check-in policy, refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx) article (apply for VS2015 with VSTS, the registry path is different, for example: For 64 bit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/WOW6432Node/Microsoft/VisualStudio/14.0/TeamFoundation/SourceControl/Checkin Policies)
2. In Evaluate method, get pendingchanges path, for example: string path= PendingCheckin.PendingChanges.CheckedPendingChanges.First().ServerItem;
3. Get build definitions of specific team project and get build definition details according build definition ID through [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-list-of-build-definitions) and check each build definition trigger path.